# How would a regex statement for Solidity pragmas look like?

Tags: solidity

Does someone have a ready-to-use regex for Solidity pragmas?

I need to perform certain actions based on what pragma the user wishes to use. (I'm writing a utility for [Foundry](https://getfoundry.sh/).)

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I'm writing a utility for [Foundry](https://getfoundry.sh/) and need to perform certain actions based on what pragma the user wishes to use.

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd want to match any pragma I suppose ? Are you looking for a split on the pragmas tokens ? (i.e., pragma solidity 0.8.0 would be returned as ['solidity', '0.8.0'])

Comment: @hroussille yep, but to start with even something like ">=MIN MAX" would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/grammar.html), a pragma is always `pragma pragma-token pragma-token pragma-token …;` where `pragma-token` is something without semicolons. This could be captured by `/^pragma [^;]+( [^;]+)*;$/`. But it really depends on what you are trying to achieve, on whether you are interested in simply matching or else also capturing, on whether you are interested in a specific type of pragma, etc.

From your comment it seems that you are interested in the *version* pragma. According to the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#version-pragma), the version follows the same [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver) syntax used by npm. So if you want to interpret the version pragma (e.g. to filter down the list of compiler versions to match the specified expression) then rather than writing a regex, it might be better to use semver package directly and/or examine how [the Solidity compiler itself](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.8.15/libsolidity/analysis/SyntaxChecker.cpp) goes about interpreting it.